# Suppose that the function f(x,y) is continuous and satisfies the generalized Lipschitz condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that the function f(x,y) is continuous and satisfies the generalized Lipschitz condition:
$|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)|\le L(x)|y_1-y_2|, (x,y_1),(x,y_2) \in S=\{(x,y) \in R^2: x_0 \le x \le x_0 +a \}$ and integral $\int _{x_0}^{x_0+a} $ exist and non infinity. Prove that if two solutions of the equation $y'=f(x,y)$ satisfy the same initial condition $y(x_0)$ then they are equal for $x \in [x_0, x_0+a]$

I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: Are you familiar with proofs of uniqueness for ODEs? Usually this is done by proving that that the differential equation gives rise to a contraction, and the result follows by fixed-point theorem.

Comment: Are you asking to prove the full existence and uniqueness theorem?

Comment: When you say the integral exist, what integral are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Let $y_1,y_2$ be two solutions passing through $(x_0,y(x_0))$. Since the solutions satisfy the differential equation we can assume that they are continuous.

Let $\phi=y_1-y_2$, and let $\eta(x) = \sup_{t \in [x_0,x]} |\phi(t) |$. Note that $\phi(x_0) = 0$, $\eta$ is continuous, non-decreasing and $\eta(x_0)=0$.

Since $L$ is integrable on $[x_0,x_0+a]$, for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find a $\delta>0$ such that if $mA < \delta$, then $\int_A L < \epsilon$.

Let $\epsilon = {1 \over 2}$, and choose $\delta$ as above for $L$. Let $h< \delta$.

Choose $ x \in [x_0,x_0+h]$.
Since $\phi'(x) = f(x,y_1(x))-f(x,y_2(x))$ and
$\phi(x)= \int_{x_0}^x (f(t,y_1(t))-f(t,y_2(t))) dt$ we have
$|\phi(x)| \le \int_{x_0}^x L(t)dt \ \eta(x)$, and so $\eta(x_0+h) \le {1 \over 2} \eta(x_0+h)$, from which it follows that $\eta(x_0+h) = 0$, and so $\phi(x) = 0$ for $x \in [x_0,x_0+h]$.

This process can be repeated on $[x_0+h, x_0+2h]$, etc. until we find that $\eta(x_0+a) = 0$.